# Default value of DataGridRow Background property

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I was messing arround with `DataGridRow`'s `Background` and I found something weird.
The background color of a `DataGridRow` appear white, and if you print it, you get the following output:

```
System.Console.WriteLine(row.Background.ToString());
-----OUTPUT-----
#FFFFFFFF
```

If you print `Brushes.White`, you get the same thing:

```
System.Console.WriteLine(Brushes.White);
-----OUTPUT-----
#FFFFFFFF
```

Now, when compairing them:

```
System.Console.WriteLine(Brushes.White.Equals(row.Background));
-----OUTPUT-----
False
```

It says that they are different, which is weird, since they both are `SolidColorBrush` with the `#FFFFFFFF` value.

Is there a specific reason for `DataGridRow` not to use `Brushes.White` ?
Is it a predefined `SolidBrushColor` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are comparing brushes, not colors. `SolidColorBrush` nor `Brush` override `Equals` method therefore your're comparing it by reference and one brush not always equals another brush with the same color. Controls will use [`SystemColors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.aspx), as defined in Windows, for default values. To compare it you need to know they are both `SolidColorBrush` and then compare `SolidColorBrush.Color`